# InfluxDB MAX value as time series

Tags: time-series, max, influxdb

In InfluxDB, I have a time series of which I would like to determine the maximum value. Using the MAX() function does return the maximum, but as a single point consisting of the maximum value and corresponding timestamp.

How can I get not just a single point, but a full series of points, each consisting of the respective original timestamp and the maximum value?

Example:

```
(T1, 4)
(T2, 7)
(T3, 5)
(T4, 4)
```

should be returned as

```
(T1, 7)
(T2, 7)
(T3, 7)
(T4, 7)
```

instead of just

```
(T2,7)
```